# How to find the 'for' loop block in any c++ code?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a task to find 'for' loop blocks in any c++ code, I only want to find the outer loop and I will write a comment at the beginning of the loop and comment at the end of the loop after the last Braces. 
**This is an example:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
        for (int n = 0; n <= 10; n++) {
            cout << "Hello" << endl;
        }
    }
    for (int y = 0; y <= 10; y++) {
        cout << "for make diffrent with x" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**and here is my code and the output after applying the code:**

```
string str;
    string findf = "for";
    ifstream infile("code.txt");
    ofstream output("output.cpp");

    if (!infile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Unable to open File";
        exit(0);
    }
    while (!infile.eof())
        {
            getline(infile, str);
            size_t spot = str.find("for");
            bool num = true;
            if ((spot != std::string::npos) && num==true)
            {
                num = false;
                string tmpstring;
                tmpstring = "//Start of the for loop\n";
                tmpstring += str.substr(spot)+"\n";
                str = tmpstring;
            }
            output << str << endl;
        }
        cout << "Done" << endl;
        infile.close();
```

**output code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
//Start of the for loop
for (int x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {

//Start of the for loop
for (int n = 0; n <= 10; n++) {

            cout << "Hello" << endl;
        }
    }
//Start of the for loop
for (int y = 0; y <= 10; y++) {

//Start of the for loop
for make diffrent with x" << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

the code finds any 'for'word even the world inside the cout and the inner loop, and I did the same with the closing braces } and it finds any } braces and did the same as 'for', how I can identify the whole for loop block so I can write a comment at the beginning and the end of the loop.

Comment: why do you need to do this? Is the block always enclosed in `{}` ?

Comment: Are you looking for [LibTooling](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html)?

Comment: You will end up writing a C parser. Only exception if you can make a lot of assumptions on the file contents. Better use an existing parser.

Comment: use we suppose all the loop will be enclosed in {} because we will be targeting loop with lots of statements inside it and we only consider the outer loop.

Comment: `while (!infile.eof()) {  getline(infile, str);` This is wrong.

Comment: LibTrooling can check the syntax as I understand from the link but Can I determine the beginning and the end using LibTrooling?

Comment: Is there any other solution that avoids me using parser?

Comment: It's not that hard to parse; just skip the contents of quoted strings and comments (neither is trivial, but with a little effort they're not that hard), and look for `for` followed by optional whitespace followed by `(`.

Comment: okay, do you recommend any existing parser?

Comment: You need to look for a non-identifier character, followed by "for", followed by a non-identifier character, and you need to ignore for-loop bodies, comments and string literals. (And hope that you don't need to worry about macros.)

Comment: Your code will fail if the word "for" is in a comment.  Name a variable `fortune` and see what happens.

Comment: Be aware that whitespace includes newlines (yes, zero or more).  You code needs to account for this (I have placed the initialization, compare and increment on separate lines before, for easier readability).

Comment: it must have macros because I am not targeting very basic code.

Comment: yes, it fails and I mentioned that in the question, you can see in the output file, you can find the cout message, and this is one of the issues that I am facing.

Comment: The way I would approach this is to read in the file line by line. For each line trim the whitespace, then you can see if that line begins with "for(". Then you'd have to solve the problem of finding where the scope of the for loop ends, which will be tricky. In a real world application (I'm assuming this is a homework/related question) you'd just find a library to do this, trying to roll your own version is always going to be bug prone.

Comment: I searched about libraries can make this process faster but I didn't find any.

Comment: `#define BREAK {`  `#define ME for` - True C parsing is hard...